Using the sceenutil package gives me an error in flutter LateInitializationError: Field '_minTextAdapt@341084504' has not been initialized
I am working on a flutter application and using the screen util package ScreenUtil, but the app gives me an error when using the child attribute to insert the Material app widget. Here is my code:`
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:spoon_app/screens/splash_screen/mobile.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const Spoon());
}

class Spoon extends StatelessWidget {
  const Spoon({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,

// when to use the child attribute it yields with an error
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0XFFFFFFFF),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            bodySmall: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.sp,
                fontFamily: "Alex",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              height: 1.3.h,

            ),
            bodyMedium: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.sp,
              fontFamily: "Alex",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
              bodyLarge: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontFamily: "Alex",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
              headlineMedium: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
              headlineLarge: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Alex",
            fontSize: 32.sp,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          )),
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: "SpoonApp",
    home: MobileWelcomeScreen(),
  ),
    );
  }
}

`
in a speedy manner, am I in much need for a fix for my problem.

please try adding ensureScreenSize: true, in ScreenUtilInit as it initialize screen size parameters

Try to use builder and child attribute like this:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScreenUtilInit(
    designSize: const Size(375, 812),
    minTextAdapt: true,
    splitScreenMode: true,
    ensureScreenSize: true,
    builder: (_ , child) {
      return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0XFFFFFFFF),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
              bodySmall: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.sp,
                fontFamily: "Alex",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                height: 1.3.h,
              ),
              bodyMedium: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.sp,
                fontFamily: "Alex",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
              bodyLarge: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontFamily: "Alex",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
              headlineMedium: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
              headlineLarge: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Alex",
                fontSize: 32.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              )),
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "SpoonApp",
        home: child,
      );
    },
    child: MobileWelcomeScreen(),
  );
}


Please add this parameter, minTextAdapt: true, // Here, provide a value for minTextAdapt
